# Add Curve Curve Tools is missing

Tags: add-on

I have version 2.80.75. I learned about the Curve Tools add on so I went into preferences to look for it, but it's just not there. This is weird cuz I've been told it's a default add on that comes with Blender. Any explanations on why this happened?

Comment: Looking at the git history for the addon and comparing that to the release dates for blender it looks like Curve Tools was added in 2.81

Comment: By the way, if you're going to stick with 2.8x, you should at least go to [2.83 LTS](https://www.blender.org/download/releases/2-83/) because there are a ton of bug fixes in it and it is still supported.

Answer (score 0):

Seems BSurfaces does about the same thing. I think in later versions that become the Curve Tools addon.